# octave symbolic divide expression as partfrac does but the factors in N-sized vector

Tags: octave, sympy

For this particular expression (but not only for it)

```
>> n(1)
ans = (sym) R₁⋅(I₁⋅(C₂⋅R₁⋅R₂⋅s + R₁ + R₂) + V₂)
```

i want what octave symbolic package's partfrac does

```
>> partfrac(n(1),I1)
ans = (sym)

     ⎛     2          2        ⎞
  I₁⋅⎝C₂⋅R₁ ⋅R₂⋅s + R₁  + R₁⋅R₂⎠ + R₁⋅V₂

>>
```

but to have the output in vector of two parts, the first index depending on *I1* and the second depending on *V2* (independent of *I1*).

In the best case for the vector of the "driving" variables *[I1 V2]* and so on, get the vector of the particular expressions, respectively zeros.

The optimal output may look as following

```
>> xyz = somefunc(n(1),[I1 V2])
xyz = (sym 2×2 matrix)

  ⎡           I₁              V₂⎤
  ⎢                             ⎥
  ⎢     2          2            ⎥
  ⎣C₂⋅R₁ ⋅R₂⋅s + R₁  + R₁⋅R₂  R₁⎦

>>
```

The solution based on embedding sympy code will be also appreciated.

Many thanks